# Not able to upload 1 GB file in Minio using java?

Tags: java, file-upload, java-8, out-of-memory, minio

I have a java program that uploads files from local to Minio browser. The file size is around 900 MB. When I'm executing the java program I get -

```
Java.lang.OutOfMemoryError - Java heap Size
```

I tried increasing heap size both in eclipse.ini as well as under `Run-->Configurations-->Project to -Xms4096M -Xmx8192M.`

After increasing the heap size when I executed the program I recieve -

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Requested array size exceeds VM limit
```

How to upload large size files to Minio using Java ?

This is how my java program looks like -

```
 StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
      File[] files = new File(path).listFiles();
      showFiles(files);
      System.out.println(pathList);
      ListIterator<String> itr=pathList.listIterator();  
      while(itr.hasNext()){
          String relativePath=itr.next();
          if(relativePath!=null) {
              String absolutePath=path+(relativePath).replaceFirst("minio_files", "");
              System.out.println(absolutePath);
              System.out.println(relativePath);
              File f =new File(absolutePath);
              BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
              String line = null;
              String ls = System.getProperty("line.separator");
              while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                stringBuilder.append(line);
                stringBuilder.append(ls);
              }
              if(stringBuilder.length()!=0) {

                  // delete the last new line separator
                  stringBuilder.deleteCharAt(stringBuilder.length() - 1);
              }
              reader.close();
            // Create a InputStream for object upload.
                ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(stringBuilder.toString().getBytes("UTF-8"));
```

Comment: how are you uploading the file? Are you trying to load it into memory first?

Answer (score 2):

Do you absolutely need to remove a trailing line separator from your text file?

If this not absolutely required you could let the minio client libraries handle the upload transparently:

```
String absolutePath=path+(relativePath).replaceFirst("minio_files", "");
File f =new File(absolutePath);
minio.putObject("bucketName", f.getName(), absolutePath);
```

According to the minio docs this allows uploads of up to 5 GB. This is easier to implement and faster than any other solution.

---

If you absolutely need to remove a trailing line separator, you should at least pre-size the `StringBuilder` (and use the correct code to remove the trailing line separator):

```
File f = new File(absolutePath);
stringBuilder.ensureCapacity((int) f.length()+2);
try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f))) {
    String line;
    String ls = System.getProperty("line.separator");
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        stringBuilder.append(line);
        stringBuilder.append(ls);
    }
    if (stringBuilder.length() != 0) {
        // delete the last new line separator
        stringBuilder.setLength(stringBuilder.length() - ls.length());
    }
}
```

Please beware that this code can never upload files larger than about 2GB:

- arrays in java cannot be larger than `Integer.MAX_VALUE-5`
- therefore `StringBuilder` cannot be used to create strings with more than `Integer.MAX_VALUE-5` characters
- transforming the string into a `UTF-8` encoded byte array cannot produce a byte array longer than `Integer.MAX_VALUE-5` bytes
- since UTF-8 is a multibyte encoding, transforming a string with `Integer.MAX_VALUE-5` characters into a byte array might not be possible

Comment: Worked. Could you explain me the relation between Integer.MAX_VALUE=5 and 2GB ?

Comment: @bosari `Integer.MAX_VALUE - 5` is the maximum array size in java. This is equal to `2^31 - 6` or `2147483642` bytes, which is short of 2 GB (2147483648 bytes)